# How to get the members from multiple security groups using ASP.NET C# WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm using the following to get the members of a particular security group in Active Directory, and add them to a datatable.  This works just fine, but I would like to modify it to add the members of multiple groups.  How can I modify the code to include three specific groups?

Here's what I am using right now:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null))
        {
            using (var group = (GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "Security Group 1")))
            {
                var users = group.GetMembers(true);
                foreach (UserPrincipal user in users)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry de = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                    dt.Rows.Add
                    (
                        Convert.ToString(de.Properties["givenName"].Value),
                        Convert.ToString(de.Properties["sn"].Value),
                        Convert.ToString(de.Properties["mail"].Value),
                        Convert.ToString(de.Properties["department"].Value),
                        Regex.Replace((Convert.ToString(de.Properties["manager"].Value)), @"CN=([^,]*),.*$", "$1")
                    );
                }
            }
        }
```

I would like to also add the members from "Security Group 2" and "Security Group 3".

Comment: Do the security groups have the same properties you need and only different members?

Comment: Yes, they have the same properties and different members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the same properties for all 3 groups and the only difference is due to the members, I would keep it simple and use a foreach loop.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null))
        {
            // Declare array to hold names of groups
            string[] groups = new string[]{"Security Group 1", "Security Group 2", "Security Group 3"};
            // Iterate through each group and perform operation
            foreach (string group in groups){
                // Notice, your hardcoded group name has been replaced with the group variable
                using (var group = (GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, group)))
                {
                    var users = group.GetMembers(true);
                    foreach (UserPrincipal user in users)
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry de = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                        dt.Rows.Add
                        (
                            Convert.ToString(de.Properties["givenName"].Value),
                            Convert.ToString(de.Properties["sn"].Value),
                            Convert.ToString(de.Properties["mail"].Value),
                            Convert.ToString(de.Properties["department"].Value),
                            Regex.Replace((Convert.ToString(de.Properties["manager"].Value)), @"CN=([^,]*),.*$", "$1")
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Or something roughly along those lines. Unless I misunderstood your requirements, that should be a simple solution to your problem.

Comment: Excellent approach @Jack.  I'm not sure why, but "group" is returning null.  Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Do you mean the foreach variable group? If so, try debugging the code and make sure the groups array is being initialized correctly. You could also try renaming the variable just in case there is some type of conflict somewhere.

Comment: The issue was with one of the security groups in AD, not with the code. It works as expected.  I changed the code a bit to name the array "sgroups".